# Trying to clone an old repo and getting PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be removed as of version 1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql

Old laptop broke so I bought a new one and got Ubuntu up and running. After installing rails I am trying to clone a repo of mine. When I try to run **rake db:create** this is the error I get:

> The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will
>   be removed as of version 1.0.
>   Blockquote You should use PG::Connection, PG::Result, and PG::Error instead, respectively.

I have searched for an answer via google and here but I have not seen anyone reply with an answer yet to the problem.

I have `Ubuntu 17.04`

Ruby `2.4.0p0`

Rails `4.2.6`

`Postgresql`

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607324/installing-newest-version-of-rails-4-with-postgres-the-pgconn-pgresult-and-p/44607369#44607369) is any help.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is change **gem 'pg'** to **gem 'pg', '0.20.0'** in your Gemfile. Enjoy